# How to toggle between the components in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I develop Three components Dashboard.vue(parent component) which contains two child components like DisplayBooks.vue and sortBooksLowtoHigh.vue .in dashboard component it will contain some options[sort by relevance] by default the sortBooksLowToHigh component should not be visisble and displayBooks component should be visible by default,when i click on price:LowtoHigh option the DisplayBooks component should be hide and sortBooksLowtoHigh component should be visible.How to achieve this thing please help me to fix this issue.

`Dashboard.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img src="../assets/education.png" alt="notFound" class="education-image" />
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <p class="brand">Bookstore</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="input-group">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            <div class="form-outline">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder='search...' />
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="right-bar">
            <li><a> <i class="far fa-user"></i></a></li>
            <p class="profile-content">profile</p>
            <li><a><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></a></li>
            <p class="cart-content">cart</p>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mid-body">
        <h6 >Books<span   class="items">(128items)</span></h6>
        
        <select  class="options" @change="applyOption">
            <option disabled value="">Sort by relevance</option>
             <option value="HighToLow">price:High to Low</option>
            <option value="LowToHigh">price:Low to High</option>
        </select>
        
    </div>
 <DisplayBooks v-show="flag" />
<sortBooksLowtoHigh v-show="!flag" />
<sortBooksHightoLow v-show="!flag" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import sortBooksLowtoHigh from './sortBooksLowtoHigh.vue'
import sortBooksHightoLow from './sortBooksHightoLow.vue'
import DisplayBooks from './DisplayBooks.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        DisplayBooks,sortBooksLowtoHigh,sortBooksHightoLow      
    },
    data() {
        return {
           flag:true,
            brand:'Bookstore',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        flip() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        applyOption(evt) {
            if(evt.target.value === 'HightoLow') this.flag = true;
            if(evt.target.value==='LowtoHigh') this.flag=true;
            else this.flag = false;
        },
    }

}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "@/styles/Dashboard.scss";
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Show DisplayBooks when flag is true and vice versa for sortBooksLowtoHigh

```
 <select class="options" @change="applyOption">
            <option disabled value="">Sort by relevance</option>
            <option value="HighToLow">price:High to Low</option>
            <option value="LowToHigh">price:Low to High</option>
 </select>
```

and

```
<DisplayBooks v-show="flag" />
<sortBooksLowtoHigh v-show="!flag" />
```

and then in

```
data() {
        return {
            flag:true,
            brand:'Bookstore',
        }
    },
methods:{
        applyOption(evt) {
            if(evt.target.value === "HightoLow") this.flag = true;
            else this.flag = false;
        },
    }
```

Note that its methods and not method

Edit:

If you gonna import a new component "sortBookHightoLow.vue" so based on your requirement what you can do is instead of setting a boolean value to the flag, you can set a text to it.
Pls check below code

```
 <select class="options" @change="applyOption">
            <option disabled value="">Sort by relevance</option>
            <option value="HighToLow">price:High to Low</option>
            <option value="LowToHigh">price:Low to High</option>
 </select>
```

and

```
<DisplayBooks v-show="flag==='noOrder'" />
<sortBooksLowtoHigh v-show="flag==='lowToHigh'" /> 
<sortBooksHightoLow v-show="flag==='highToLow'" />
```

and then in

```
data() {
        return {
            flag:'noOrder',
            brand:'Bookstore',
        }
    },
methods:{
        applyOption(evt) {
            if(evt.target.value === "HightoLow") this.flag = 'highToLow';
            else this.flag ='lowToHigh';
        },
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,@Amaarrockz, it's working fine but double quotes missing in vlaue =" " section  in your answer

Comment: Ya, I corrected it, Btw if my answer helped please do accept and upvote it...thanks :)

Comment: it's super working your answer , i like the way ur writing and explaining

Comment: i have one more doubt can you please help me .@Amaarrockz

Comment: sure! why not! I ll

Comment: i want to import another component inside my Dashboard.vue ,the component name is sortBookHightoLow.vue , if i select price:high to low option at that time my DisplayBooks.vue and sortBookLowtoHigh.vue should be hide and only sortBookHightoLow.vue component should be visible ....

Comment: i updated my question , i am trying like you suggested only but it's not working

Comment: when i click on price:high to Low option it doesn't display that component ..

Comment: Please re-check and see if you copied my answer right

Comment: yeah @Amaarrockz, i copied your updated answer only

Comment: Great, glad that helped

Comment: sorry to trouble you brother , it's not working even if i set a child routing also